# Django - URL configuration

Tags: django, django-urls

Here is something i wanna ask if i try this code i can go to login page but my url look like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/%2Flogin/`. What is this `%2F`?

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("<str:slug>", views.redirect, name='redirect'),
path('/login/', views.logIn, name='login')]
```

And i remove slash from login url i get an error message

> Page not found (404) Request Method:
>   GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000//login/

after removing slashes here is the code

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("<str:slug>", views.redirect, name='redirect'),
path('login', views.logIn, name='login')]
```

So, i wanna know is that why are the slashes affecting the url for login but not `<str:slug>`

Comment: `%2F` is encoded url character `/` , browser will automatically encodes/decodes it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", views.logIn, name='login'),
    path("<str:slug>/", views.redirect, name='redirect'),
    path("", views.index, name="index")
]
```

The order of the entries matter and always add a trailing `/`, unless you have root like `views.index`

Comment: It worked but i wanna know that if i add a new url it should be above login url or at the last.

Comment: It depends on the new url. As a rule of thumb, if you hardcode a string like "login/", it should come before any path, that expected a string (like <str:slug>). Because for Django, if <str:slug> at top, "login/" would match that criteria. So it would tread "login" as a slug and use "views.redirect". So now that "login/" is before the slug, it will first check of the string is "login", if not, it will go on to the next path, which is "<str:slug>". And so on...